# Why does Go slice `append()` not take a reference?

Tags: go

Go Lang's slice `append()` might allocate a new backing array to make room for the new item. Thus, after a call `z = append(x,y)`, if `z`'s front most elements are modified, `x` is essentially unspecified -- it might or might not have the same backing array as `z`, and `z` could mutate its backing array with `z[0] = foo`, which thus might or might not modify `x`'s backing array.

So, why let this ugliness surface? Instead making it a program bug to assign the result of append to anything but its first argument, why not have `append` take a `*[]T` instead, so no reassignment is needed and no undefined variable is left dangling.

This wouldn't solve every case, because `a = x; append(&x,y)` would still make `a` undefined, but a partial improvement seems better than none.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite true that in your first example (`z = append(x, y)`), `x` is undefined. Instead, `x` still points to the original contents of `x`, while `z` points to those contents and then some. As you mention, there are two possibilities:

- `cap(x) > len(x)`, in which case `append` simply returns `x[:len(x)+1]` (ie, extends the length of the returned slice to contain one extra element)
- `cap(x) == len(x)`, in which case `append` creates another array by copying over the contents of `x` and then appends `y` as the `len(x)`-th element.

In either of these cases, `x` is left largely unchanged in the sense that all of the elements of `x` are still there. You obviously have to be careful now that you potentially have two references to the same underlying data, but the point stands that keeping `x` around can be useful.

That said, I agree that maybe having `append` take a pointer might be simpler, and maybe this possible use case that I've just described isn't common enough to warrant the potentially confusing, mildly more verbose semantics.

Comment: Modified my intro to clarify that modifying `z` makes `x` have unspecified contents.